# Printing a rather specific matrix

Tags: python, matrix, printing

I have a list consisting of 148 entries. Each entry is a four digit number. I would like to print out the result as this:

```
1    14    27    40
2    15    28    41
3    16    29    42
4    17    30    43
5    18    31    44
6    19    32    45
7    20    33    46
8    21    34    47
9    22    35    48
10   23    36    49
11   24    37    50
12   25    38    51
13   26    39    52
53
54
55... and so on
```

I have some code that work for the first 13 rows and 4 columns:

```
kort_identifier = [my_list_with_the_entries]
print_val = 0
print_num_1 = 0
print_num_2 = 13
print_num_3 = 26
print_num_4 = 39

while (print_val <= 36):
    print kort_identifier[print_num_1], '%10s' % kort_identifier[print_num_2], '%10s' % kort_identifier[print_num_3], '%10s' % kort_identifier[print_num_4]
    print_val += 1
    print_num_1 += 1
    print_num_2 += 1
    print_num_3 += 1
    print_num_4 += 1
```

I feel this is an awful solution and there has to be a better and simpler way of doing this. I have searched through here (searched for printing tables and matrices) and tried those solution but none seems to work with this odd table/matrix behaviour that I need.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is your matrix of the form `[[1, 14, 27, 40], [2, 15, 28, 41], ...]`, `[1, 14, 27, 40, 2, 15, 28, 41, ...]`, or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`?

Comment: Zip! http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip You'll have to do some awkward slicing prior to zipping, but that's to be expected since what you want is a pretty awkward output.

Comment: @Bill My matrix consists of 13 rows 4 columns for the first 52 numbers then another 13 rows 4 columns for the next 52.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a deck-of-cards type project?

Comment: @JoeFrambach Its actually me trying to do a prof of concept about the Danish PKI system for my study-oriented-project in December - just started doing the preparations :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit tricky, but here you go. I opted to manipulate the list until it had the right shape, instead of messing around with indexes.

```
lst = range(1, 149)
lst = [lst[i:i+13] for i in xrange(0, len(lst), 13)]
lst = zip(*[lst[i] + lst[i+4] + lst[i+8] for i in xrange(4)])

for row in lst:
    for col in row:
        print col,
    print
```

Comment: Now that is a lot prettier than mine - Thanks!

Comment: @Evilunclebill always my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be overkill, but you could just make a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(kort_identifier).reshape(2, 13, 4)
for subarray in x:
    for row in subarray:
        print row
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help! This is a great alternative to Oscars.